# Removed all files from Kindle device via cp command

Tags: files, ram, cp, kindle

I tried to copy a file to a Kindle device via command line in the following way:

```
cp filename /dev/sdb5
```

where `sdb5` is the name of that device.
As result, all files from the Kindle device are removed.
Furthermore, `sdb5` is not mounted since there, the Kindle device is not recognized on Linux anymore.
I cannot open the device folder (because it doesn't exist), neither can I upload any files to it (via calibri, e-mail etc).
On my Kindle device the free memory is shown as 88mb, although the device is empty, hence there should 8 Gb of storage memory.

Please help me to understand what the problem is, why `cp` removed all the files?
How to mount Kindle on Linux, so that there will be 8Gb as before?
I will appreciate any ideas and hints!

Answer (score 1):

You should *never* copy directly on a device.

If you copy directly on a device you usually erase the partition information on that device or partition of a device.

Instead you should copy on a mounted directory linked to that device or partition of device, that usually is mounted on /media/yourusername/devicename

For the Kindle I think you should to a factory reset to fix it and try again.